# Scaling Emitter Without Affecting Particle System Appearance

Tags: particles, metaballs

I have created a stylized fire according to this tutorial using metaballs and a particle system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qaC9vUUvrE

Now my problem is that I would like to scale down the fire quite a bit. However, since it involves a particle system, when changing the scale of the emitter, all of the particle / metaball settings would have to be changed such that it looks the same as before. And even then I guess it would be pretty hard to achieve the same exact look. I have tried that but I don't really get the same result. My question is if it's somehow possible to change the size of the fire while keeping it's exact look.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.